# Do I have to worry about memory leaks with Rx.NET FromEventPattern?

Tags: c#, .net, events, system.reactive

In .NET I've been essentially raised to never ever forget to unsubscribe to events. In MVVM apps what I often end up with is this construct.

```
public class WindowVm
{
    public EntityModel MyModel { get; set; }

    void Subscribe()
    {
        MyModel.PropertyChanged += DoSomething;
    }

    void Unsubscribe()
    {
        MyModel.PropertyChanged -= DoSomething;
    }
}
```

I need to unsubscribe, because if I don't MyModel would keep a reference to the WindowVm and keep it alive for as long as MyModel lives.

I just found out about reactive extensions, but I can't find out whether I need to still think about this. I cant find anywhere that says so, but I also don't hear "oh and btw it solves that annoying event unsubscribe problem" which would be a killer argument.

```
public class WindowVm
{
    public EntityModel MyModel { get; set; }

    void Subscribe()
    {
        MyModel.PropChangedObservable.Subscribe(e => DoSomething(e.Sender, e.EventArgs));
    }
}
public class EntityModel : ObservableBase
{
    public IObservable<EventPattern<PropertyChangedEventArgs>> PropChangedObservable { get; private set; }

    public EntityModel()
    {
        PropChangedObservable = Observable
               .FromEventPattern<PropertyChangedEventHandler, PropertyChangedEventArgs>(
                   x => this.PropertyChanged += x,
                   x => this.PropertyChanged -= x);
    }
}
```

I can't tell whether this would create an extra reference. And what about this way?

```
public class WindowVm
{
    public EntityModel MyModel { get; set; }

    void Subscribe()
    {
        Observable
               .FromEventPattern<PropertyChangedEventHandler, PropertyChangedEventArgs>(
                   x => MyModel.PropertyChanged += x,
                   x => MyModel.PropertyChanged -= x)
               .Subscribe(e => DoSomething(e.Sender, e.EventArgs));
    }
}
```

Comment: Funnily enough this was exactly the selling point in a video uploaded by the dotNET YouTube channel just yesterday: [On .NET Live - Common usage patterns for Reactive Extensions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U-vznhAzSCo&t=1336). At around 22:16 Michael Stonis praises Rx for being able to clean up itself afterwards automatically.

Comment: Yes I saw this earlier. he says "When we're DONE or when we're not interested anymore, this is what will be called". When am I DONE listening for an event? I never say I am. I never call dispose. I would love it when it gets called when either WindowVm oder MyModel get garbage collected. That's my question I guess.

Comment: Yes, your question is very logical, and answering it is actually not that easy. I am not sure that I could provide an answer that would be more informative than this tutorial: [Intro to Rx - Part 1 - Lifetime management](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/03_LifetimeManagement.html). My understanding is that if you don't dispose the Rx subscription, the underlying subscription to the `PropertyChanged` event will not be unsubscribed, as long as the publisher (the `WindowVm` instance) remains alive.

Comment: I'm talking about a subscription to the `FromEventPattern` observable you are showing in your question, This one has no completion condition. But if you chain some operator like the `Take` or the `TakeWhile` or the `TakeUntil`, then the derived observable will be "completable". When it completes all existing subscriptions will be disposed automatically, causing the unsubscription from the underlying event. Chaining Rx operators creates observables that when subscribed a chain reaction occurs, and the same when unsubscribed. Each operator propagates the sub-unsub request to its parent operator.

Answer (score 1):

I have not worked with RX but the Subscribe method that you are using is returning an IDisposable which should then be used by the consumer to unsubscribe.
Your method:

```
void Subscribe()
{    
    MyModel.PropChangedObservable.Subscribe(e => DoSomething(e.Sender, e.EventArgs));
}
```

Should then be:

```
IDisposable Subscribe()
{    
    return MyModel.PropChangedObservable.Subscribe(e => DoSomething(e.Sender, e.EventArgs));
}
```

*Note: I'm guessing your code is not 100% complete as you are missing the method to be invoked on `Subscribe` and you have hard-coded `DoSomething` and I'm ignoring that part*

So the observer of your model would first call subscribe and acquire the reference to IDisposable. Once the observer is finished then it should call `Dispose` on that reference.

To answer your question

> I can't find out whether I need to still think about this

The answer is yes, you still need to think about this. However the RX does have automatic unsubscription but you need to know how many events you want to listen to. Check the answer of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22789589/561341).

Answer (score 0):

I am using this approach in WinForms and it will also work for WPF.
Unfortunately, it changes the generated code, but VS won't replace it when you change things in designer.

```
public MainForm()
{
    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

}
```

Open InitializeComponent method and in designer file change dispose method.

```
    'UserControl overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
            OnDisposing() // <-- Add this line
            components.Dispose()
        End If
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Sub
```

Implement OnDispose under the ctor (I usually place it before Load)

```
public void OnDisposing()
{
    var context = // TODO: get VM for current frm;
    if (context != null)
        context.Dispose(); // call dispose on VM.
}
```

Your VM should then unsubscribe in on Dispose method that will be called when UC is disposed (or later :D ). That will work OK for dialogs etc.